# Makefile target from variable overrides unexpected target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to create make a target by prefixing `bootload_` onto a list variable in Make.  Here is my file:

```
cs00:
    echo "in original target cs00"
cs01:
    echo "in original target cs01"

BOOTLOAD_ENABLED:=cs00 cs01

bootload_$(BOOTLOAD_ENABLED):
    echo "in bootload $@"
```

When I run `make bootload_cs00` I get this output:

```
Makefile:9: warning: overriding recipe for target 'cs01'
Makefile:4: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'cs01'
echo "in bootload bootload_cs00"
in bootload bootload_cs00
```

I don't understand why this is overriding the original target?  What am I missing here.

Comment: To clarify Maxim's answer: you write `bootload_$(BOOTLOAD_ENABLED)` where `BOOTLOAD_ENABLED` is `cs00 cs01`, so the expansion of your target is `bootload_cs00 cs01`: the `booload_` is prefixed only with the first element in `BOOTLOAD_ENABLED` not every element.  To get that prefix on every element you have to use a function as Maxim describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootload_$(BOOTLOAD_ENABLED)` expands to `bootload_cs00 cs01`, i.e. it is just string concatenation.

You can prefix **all** words in a variable with `patsubst`, `addprefix`, or substitution references. E.g.:

```
BOOTLOAD_ENABLED:=cs00 cs01
$(info $(addprefix bootload_,${BOOTLOAD_ENABLED}))
$(info $(patsubst %,bootload_%,${BOOTLOAD_ENABLED}))
$(info ${BOOTLOAD_ENABLED:%=bootload_%})
```

They all print same `bootload_cs00 bootload_cs01` string.

See [Functions for Transforming Text](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Functions) for full details.